# Mostrar código em textarea

Tags: php, html

O que eu pretendo e mostrar no meu web site dentro de um textarea codigo php html e etc mas sempre que tento fazer ele corre o codigo e eu quero que ele mostre dentro de um text area ou e outro sistema qualquer exatamento como aqui no stack overflow

```
<section class="bg-light" id="links">
  <div class="container">

    <h1 class="text-center text-info">Teste PHP</h1>

      <?php
          echo"Olá, Mundo!";
          echo("<h2>Olá, Mundo</h2>");
          ?>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
<section class="bg-light">
  <hr></hr>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="comment" class="text-info">Código feito:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" id="codigo">Conteudo a apresentar</textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Tem como adicionar o código que tentou fazer na pergunta?

Comment: Sim!! Erro meu 1s

Comment: O Conteudo a apresentar é o sitio onde eu quero por o conteudo a mostrar o site

Comment: Nao necessita de ser em um text area mas se possível mehor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa encodar todos os html entities. A maioria das linguagens já tem alguma maneira automática de fazer o escape do código.

Em Java, utilizando JSTL no JSP, você pode fazer assim:

```
<c:out value="${valorAqui}" escapeXml="true"/>
```

Em PHP, há a função htmlentities que você usa:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($texto); ?>
```

Não cheguei a está, mas acredito que de forma simples você também poderia imprimir o código php da seguinte forma dentro do HTML:

```
<?php echo '<?php //aqui você insere seu código... ?>' ?>
```

Veja:

```
<section class="bg-light" id="links">
  <div class="container">

    <h1 class="text-center text-info">Teste PHP</h1>

      <?php
          echo"Olá, Mundo!";
          echo("<h2>Olá, Mundo</h2>");
          ?>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
<section class="bg-light">
  <hr></hr>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="comment" class="text-info">Código feito:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" id="codigo"><?php echo htmlentities($conteudoParaApresentar); ?></textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: <?php echo htmlentities($texto); ?>E eu posso colocar isso dentro do text area??

Comment: Obrigado Salvou-me a vida Ahah

Comment: pode sim, postei um exemplo utilizando seu código. No caso, bastaria substituir a variável $texto pela variável que contem o código html.

Comment: então e no caso de eu não querer a variável mas eu mesmo escrever o código tenho de igualar a essa mesma variável antes? ?

Comment: Neste caso, se não deseja utilizar variável basta fazer assim: ```<?php echo htmlentities('<p>aqui vem todo o código!</p><hr><br>Tudo funciona!'); ?>```

Comment: Obrigado por tudo!!  ajudou imenso!! e desculpe qualquer coisa

Comment: Testei sem o `htmlentities` e funcionou de mesmo jeito.

Comment: Também funciona, mas htmlentitles faz uma codificação, conforme documentação oficial: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php, já ao omitir essa função você não está escapando nada, somente imprimindo, em alguns casos pode não funcionar.